# Magento 2 controller_action_predispatch observer not working as expected

Tags: magento2, event-observer, cache, home-page

I have created a Observer **controller_action_predispatch** which triggers in all page.

Some thing happens strange with this When I clear all cache and login for the first time the observer triggers in home page but when I refresh or relogin it not triggering.

But it works in all other page even after refresh or second login it triggers.

How can I fix this.

I have made a echo of Action Name which comes on first login after cache clear.

```
sudo php bin/magento cache:clean;
sudo php bin/magento cache:flush;
```

[image]

For Second refresh and second login its not working

[image]

events.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="controller_action_predispatch">
        <observer name="restrict_website" instance="Test\Dev\Model\RestrictWebsite" />
    </event>
</config>
```

RestrictWebsite.php

```
<?php


namespace SahiSdi\Dev\Model;

use Magento\Customer\Model\Context;
use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;

class RestrictWebsite implements ObserverInterface
{
    protected $_storeManager;

    /**
     * RestrictWebsite constructor.
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface $eventManager,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http $response,
        \Magento\Framework\UrlFactory $urlFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\App\ActionFlag $actionFlag,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
    )
    {
        $this->_response = $response;
        $this->_urlFactory = $urlFactory;
        $this->_context = $context;
        $this->_actionFlag = $actionFlag;
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
    }

    /**
     * @param Observer $observer
     * @return void
     */
    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        $request = $observer->getEvent()->getRequest();
        $actionFullName = strtolower($request->getFullActionName());
        echo $actionFullName;
    }
}
```

Comment: In which page, you want to use predispatch?

Comment: @fernandus did you found any solution for this? I am also facing the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Use like this and flush cache:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="controller_action_predispatch_cms_index_index">
        <observer name="restrict_website" instance="Test\Dev\Model\RestrictWebsite" />
    </event>
</config>
```

Comment: getting the same issue not working after refresh and second login

Answer (score 0):

Try `controller_front_send_response_before` event instead.

Actually there are no other events fired on all pages including CMS without 
 cache issues. So there is no choice

Comment: Please give more detail of why you suggest using `controller_front_send_response_before`

Answer (score 0):

For testing you have to check the impact on frontend in a fresh incognitive window every time.
As the below 2 line set the the current guest comtomer session with a redirection, even you remove redirection from a page later on, it will contineu to redirct to customer login page due to guest customer session.

```
$this->_customerSession->setBeforeAuthUrl($this->_urlInterface->getCurrentUrl());

$this->_customerSession->authenticate();
```

So just take care while testing the result of this moudle, It will not good okay if you do not use fresh incognitive window, and cache flush command

Answer (score 0):

**file:- etc/events.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
<event name="controller_action_predispatch">
    <observer name="yourvendor_yourmodule_observer_controller_actionpredispatch_controller_action_predispatch" instance="YourVendor\YourModule\Observer\Controller\ActionPredispatch"/>
</event>
```

**file:- YourVendor\YourModule\Observer\Controller\ActionPredispatch.php**

```
    <?php
    namespace [Vendor]\[Module]\Observer\Controller\;

    use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
    use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

    class ActionPredispatch implements ObserverInterface{
        public function execute(Observer $
            $controller = $observer->getControllerAction();
        }
    }
```